# Change of variable in an integration

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

I'm working on a project, which requires the following numerical integration:

$$\frac{a^j}{\Gamma(j)}\int_{-\infty}^t f(s) e^{-a(t-s)}(t-s)^{j-1}ds$$
for some bounded continuous function $f$. Now, the problem at hand is really to evaluate $$\frac{a^j}{\Gamma(j)}\int_{-\infty}^te^{-a(t-s)}(t-s)^{j-1}ds$$
because since $f$ is bounded, I don't really care about it for now.

I want to use the change of variables $$u=e^{-\frac{a}{j}(t-s)}$$

but when I do, I must be making an error somewhere, because after the change of variable, the transformed integral does not give the same value as the one I started out with. Here is what I was doing:

$$u=e^{-\frac{a}{j}(t-s)} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{j}{a}\log(u) = t-s.$$
Also,

$$ du = \frac{a}{j}e^{-\frac{a}{j}(t-s)}ds \Rightarrow ds = \frac{j}{a}e^{\frac{a}{j}(t-s)}du$$

Then, having determined what $ds$ is in terms of $u$, and making the appropriate substitutions, I get that 
\begin{align*}
     && &\frac{a^j}{\Gamma(j)}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-a(t-s)}(t-s)^{j-1}ds&&\\
     && &= \frac{a^j}{\Gamma(j)}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-a(-\frac{j}{a}\log(u))} \left(\frac{-j}{a}\log(u)\right)^{j-1} \frac{j}{a} e^{\frac{a}{j}\left(\frac{-j}{a}\right)\log(u)}du &&\\
&& &= \frac{j^j}{\Gamma(j)}\int^1_0 u^{j-1}(-\log(u))^{j-1}du&&
\end{align*}

Except this is wrong...and I don't know why. Punching in the value of the original integral into Wolfram Alpha, I know what the integral I have performed the change of variables on should evaluate to, except it doesn't evaluate to what it should.

I don't think it's an algebraic manipulation error, but rather something to do with how I'm changing variables. I guess I am missing something in my reasoning with respect to this.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just use $u = a(t -s)$. That should be sufficient. The resulting expression would then become the expression for gamma function.

Comment: @sudeep5221 thank you for the response, but I can't use the substitution you suggest--I need the transformed interval of integration to be of finite length. My question was about why my reasoning is failing here, since the original integral and the transformed integral should evaluate to the same thing.

Comment: I don't think you have made any mistake. I plugged in W|A and got the same result in both of them. Maybe you forgot the leading constant?

Comment: @sudeep5221 well then I guess I made a silly mistake somewhere, thank you for taking the time to confirm on your end! I'm relieved I apparently still know how to do basic calculus...

Comment: Note that $\Gamma (z) = \int_{0}^{1}log(1/u)^{j-1}du$

Comment: @P.Gillich No problem! :)